# typescript, what is the type of a new Promise object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, promise

In TS, I have a function like:

```
function a() : FOO {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //omitted
  })
}
```

What is the proper type to write at `FOO`?
Is it good to just say `Promise<any>` ?

Perhaps it's helpful to show more details for what I am returning in function `a`:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const cmd = spawn(str, null, { shell: true });

    cmd.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        //just logging
    });

    cmd.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      return reject(data);
    });

    cmd.on("error", (error) => {
      return reject(error);
    });

    cmd.on("close", (code) => {
      return resolve(code);
    });
  });
```

Comment: What does the promise resolve to?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Tears and disappointment, like most promises :-D

Comment: `Promise<Tears|Disappointment>`? 

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Possibly even `Promise<Tears & Disappointment>`. I mean, it **is** 2020... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what type the fulfillment value of the promise will be. For instance, if the promise will be fulfilled with a `number`, then the type would be `Promise<number>`. For example:

```
function a() : Promise<number> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        doSomeCallbackBasedThing((err: Error | null, result: number) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

If it is fulfilled with `undefined` via `resolve()` with no argument, typically you'd write `Promise<void>`.

Often, you don't have to write the type explicitly at all; TypeScript can often infer it from the code in the function.

---

Re your edit: You'd use `Promise<x>` where `x` is the type of the `code` parameter you receive in your handler for the `close` event.